# How can I find out the memory usage of a Virtual PC VM through the host?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, memory-management

If I start a VM using Virtual PC then Task Manager does not show the memory usage of the VM. For example, right now I have a Windows 7 VM running. I have:

```
VMWindow.exe  60MB RAM
vpc.exe       24MB RAM
```

The VM claims it is using 580MB (as shown by `commit (MB)` in its Task Manager). How can I see this memory usage on my (host) PC?

Comment: You have to look at the VM itself, not the process managing its window. Click on the "show tasks from all users" button.

Comment: I already have 'show tasks from all users' checked

Comment: You should be able to find the VM itself then. It'll be the process using all the memory. :)

Comment: That is the point of my question - it isn't in the list. The largest item in my list is FireFox (340MB) (what a surprise) followed by svchost (217MB).

Answer (score 0):

In task manager, go to View -> Select Columns, and enable the Memory - Commit Size column.  Note that this is the amount of memory you configured the VM to think it has, not how much it is actually using, which is the number task manager normally shows.

Comment: Commit size on the VM (well VMWindows) is 64MB, so it isn't that.

Comment: @Rob, I'm not sure how virtualpc works.  Maybe vmwindow is just the interface, and vpc is the actual virtual machine?